# Git doesn't allow rebase because of unstaged changes when there are none

Tags: git, git-rebase

When I try `git rebase` I see the following:

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

When I try `git status` I see the following:

```
On branch xxx

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I've already tried `git reset`, `git clean -fd` and `git checkout .`

What else can I try?

Comment: Have you run `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git update-index --skip-worktree` on any file before? Try `git ls-files -v | grep -e '^h' -e '^S'` to find them out.

Comment: Nope, I haven't run those commands. I tried your `git ls-files` command and it returned nothing. I tried running `git ls-files -v` and it seems all files are `H`.

Comment: Is there any file which is ignored on the current branch and exists in the worktree but committed on the new base?

Comment: I've tried `git rebase -i HEAD~1` but it also fails and my last commit definitely didn't introduce any ignored files.

Answer (score -1):

I gave up and nuked the repository: `cd .. && rm -rf <repo> && git clone <repo>`

Rebasing works now.

Comment: Next time, try "Reset current branch to here..."

Comment: This is not an answer to any question except “How do I delete a Git repository?”.